# PHP: Slim Framework - using different response header per route

Tags: php, slim

is it possible to use a different response header in every route?

You can see my sourcecode here:

1. Indexfile:

https://github.com/Damian89/slim-filecaching/blob/master/index.php

2. Caching Middleware:

https://github.com/Damian89/slim-filecaching/blob/master/Caching.slim.php

I have two simple routes. I like to use caching only in the first case, not the second one - but it's not working.

If you place the following code directly above the first route it works:

```
$app->response->headers->set( PageCaching::SLIM_PAGE_CACHER, PageCaching::CACHE_ENABLED);
```

But in this case both routes are cached.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like your caching logic in middleware is reversed. In `/no-cache/` route you set the `SLIM_PAGE_CACHER` header to `CACHE_DISABLED` whose value is `1`.

In middleware you compare the `SLIM_PAGE_CACHER` header to `CACHE_ENABLED` whose value is `0`. This becomes:

`$this->skip_caching (1 == 0); /* This evaluates to false */`

This means `skip_caching` is false and the page will be cached.

In general it is good idea to avoid double negatives in code. They make code hard to read and understand. It is also good idea to follow conventions and assume `1 === true` and `0 === false`, not the vice versa.

Comment: You are right, but that was an old version of this file. I added the new one. Still - its not the problem. Setting new header-values does not work within routes.

Comment: Just tested and $app->response->headers->set("X-Test", "foo") works ok. There is logic error somewhere in your code.

Comment: Damn... it works for me too, but only outside the route -like: `$app->add( new \PageCaching() ); $app->response->headers->set( PageCaching::SLIM_PAGE_CACHER, PageCaching::CACHE_ENABLED);` In this case, the second route ("/no-cache/" has still CACHE_ENABLED, despite I defined within the route CACHE_DISABLED.

Comment: Works inside route too.

Comment: mhm... you are right, its possible, but not passed into my middleware!